# How to write Text on a image.

Tags: html, css

How to add TEXT in the image...so that the TEXT is view-able only when the image becomes dark when mouse is placed over it.. something like ..the one given in the example image below...
Thanks for your help.

```css
.image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image img {
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
.image:hover img { /* Darkening effect on mouseover */
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.image .arrow { /* Creates a half triangle with top and left arrow transparent */
  opacity: 0;
  border-color: transparent #f2f2f2 #f2f2f2 transparent;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  position: relative;
}
.image:hover .arrow { /* Mouseover effect */
  opacity: 1;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
}


.image:hover .arrow {
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 45px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0;
}
.image .arrow {
    border-color: transparent #f2f2f2 #f2f2f2 transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.image .arrow span {
    left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/sports" />
  <div class="arrow"><span>></span></div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41NnC.png)

Comment: It looks like it's working.  What's your problem?

Comment: how to display text on the image..when the shadow comes on the image...that's what the problem is.

Comment: It does display text (in Chrome at least).  You may want to change the ">" to something less HTML like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Create some text inside your wrapper div, then order the text to display on hovering the wrapper. Below is a demo of this logic.

The HTML:

```
<div class="image">
   <p>I'm some very interesting text!</p>
  <div class="arrow"><span>></span></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
 p{
   color: #fff;
   opacity: 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   font-size:32px;
   color: red;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
   transition: all .5 ease;
}


.image:hover p {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/bVmvBP?editors=110)

Comment: how to bring the text in centre?..and how to bold the text?...when i try to manipulate with the font and size of the text..the hovering effect of the text goes off...

Comment: when i use ur code..it shows a blank screen in place of a image.

Comment: There must be something else wrong in your code, because it works fine on my end and the demo

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create like this
you need to change the position of the .image class so that text div can appear overlap on that

```css
.image-hover-wrapper {
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: -125px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.image:hover > .image-hover-wrapper{
   display:block;
   opacity:0.8;    
   transition-property: animation;
   transition-duration: 2s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;   
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/sports" />
  <div class="arrow"><span></span></div>
   <div class="image-hover-wrapper">
      Hii 
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is the 
**[Updated DEmo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr40et3L/2/)**

Comment: The shadow effect of the images(on placing mouse) goes off..anyways thanks for answering!!!

Comment: @harsher please look out the updated answer as you said about shadow effect